# Program that logs the CPU usage in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, cpu-usage

Is there any program that logs the CPU usage of all programs? I want to know, over a period of one month, which programs use the CPU more intensely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows has this built-in. It's called the [Performance Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749115.aspx). Create a [data collector set](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749337.aspx) to start collecting performance data.

Comment: Can i see the past usages. I can see the live usage in graphs but i want to see old enteries like yesterday , past month

Comment: No, you'll need to create a [data collector set](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749337.aspx) first. Then it will start recording logs.

Comment: @Amazed you need to add this to your answer..